# Why isn't this edit by the orignal poster automatically approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Why was this [pending edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/166163) not automatically approved?  I thought that original posters could always edit their own content?

It looks like there may be an issue regarding the user's ID or account.  The user is listed with the same username under 2 different profiles.  One is [unregistered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/132490/xprog660) and the other is marked [registered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/132491/xprog660).

Is this a bug or did the user accidentally create 2 different accounts?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. The edit was not automatically approved because the user used a different account to edit the post than they used to write it.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you will notice is that **while both user accounts appear to have the same name, they have differing reputations and profile pictures**.

The edit was not suggested by the original user, or atleast, not from the original account.